# Getting ECOMMRESET when trying to run webkit in docker on aws deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, cypress, webkit

## Docker file:

FROM cypress/included:12.14.0

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y git curl openssh-client

ENV GATSBY_IS_DOCKER=true

RUN mkdir -p /root/.cache/Cypress/12.14.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/yargs-unparser/node_modules/yargs/locales

RUN npx cypress cache clear

RUN npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli@10.5.2 gatsby-cli@4.24.0 mocha mochawesome mochawesome-merge mochawesome-report-generator serve wait-on cypress@12.6.0 cypress-data-session cypress-fail-fast cypress-file-upload cypress-fail-fast cypress-file-upload cypress-iframe cypress-localstorage-commands cypress-parallel cypress-pipe cypress-real-events cypress-wait-until

RUN npx playwright install --with-deps webkit

ENV PATH /e2e/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

RUN ls -la /e2e

ENTRYPOINT [ "bash", "-c" ]

## amplify.yml file

version: 1
backend:
phases:
preBuild:
commands:
- yarn updateProdBE
build:
commands:
- amplifyPush --simple
frontend:
phases:
preBuild:
commands:
# - yarn updateProdFE # this is for the --prod flag
# we'll instead install all dev deps too so we can utilise
# the caching which isn't available at the test stage below
# - nvm use 18
- yarn
build:
commands:
# - gatsby clean && gatsby build
- gatsby build
artifacts:
baseDirectory: public
files:
- '**/*'
cache:
paths:
- node_modules/**/*
- public/**/*
- .cache/**/*
- /root/.cache/**/*
test:
artifacts:
baseDirectory: cypress
configFilePath: '**/mochawesome.json'
files:
- '**/*.png'
- '**/*.mp4'
phases:
preTest:
commands:
- yarn add cypress@12.14.0
# - yarn add mocha mochawesome mochawesome-merge mochawesome-report-generator serve wait-on # this are now in package.json
- 'npx serve -l 8000 -s public & npx wait-on --timeout 20000 [http://127.0.0.1:8000'](http://127.0.0.1:8000%27)

```
test:
  commands:
    # ! REVERT TO staging
    - ENV=brand yarn jest:prod
    - cypress install
    - npm install -g playwright
    # - npx webkit install
    # - npx playwright-webkit install
    - npx playwright install-deps
    # - test $? -eq 0 || exit 1 #if jest fails exit
    - 'NO_COLOR=1 npx cypress run --browser webkit --env timestamp=$(date +%s),environment=${ENV} --reporter mochawesome --reporter-options "reportDir=cypress/report/mochawesome-report,overwrite=false,html=false,json=true,timestamp=mmddyyyy_HHMMss"'

postTest:
  commands:
    - mkdir -p cypress/report/mochawesome-report/
    - npx mochawesome-merge@4 cypress/report/mochawesome-report/*.json > cypress/report/mochawesome.json
    - npx kill-port 8000
```

works fine on local with docker, works fine on AWS with other browsers, but gets the error immediately with webkit.

Error:
Running:  TC01.Signup.cy.js                                                              (1 of 26)
2023-08-03T20:03:30.352Z [INFO]: HTTP  8/3/2023 8:03:30 PM 127.0.0.1 GET /__socket-graphql
2023-08-03T20:03:30.357Z [INFO]: HTTP  8/3/2023 8:03:30 PM 127.0.0.1 Returned 200 in 5 ms
2023-08-03T20:03:30.373Z [INFO]: write ECONNRESET
2023-08-03T20:03:30.374Z [INFO]: Error: write ECONNRESET
at afterWriteDispatched (node:internal/stream_base_commons:160:15)
at writeGeneric (node:internal/stream_base_commons:151:3)
at Socket._writeGeneric (node:net:817:11)
at Socket._write (node:net:829:8)
at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12)
at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:330:10)
at Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:334:10)
at IncomingMessage.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:754:22)
at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:527:28)
at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
at HTTPParser.parserOnBody (node:_http_common:141:24)
at Socket.socketOnData (node:_http_client:494:22)
at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)
at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23)
2023-08-03T20:03:30.469Z [INFO]: # Completed phase: test

Any assistance would be very much appreciated